# Separate a string and a float number with fscanf in C

Tags: scanf

I am trying to read from a file which contains one line of data format as GOOG|588.88

I want to copy GOOG into ticker, and copy 588.88 into a float stockprice

I have written the following code to do the job where fr is the file pointer

```
char tempprice[10]; 
char ticker[10];
fscanf(fr,"%[^|]|%[^\n]\n",ticker,tempprice);
float stockprice = stof(tempprice); //change string to float
```

The code works OK for ticker, but does not work for stockprice. In other words, GOOG is successfully copied into ticker, whereas 588.88 not. Can anyone help me on that?

Is there any better codes? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd just:

```
char tempprice[10]; 
char ticker[10];
char tmp_chr = fgetc(fr);
char *tmp_ptr = ticker;
while (tmp_chr != '|')
{
  *tmp_ptr++ = tmp_chr;
  tmp_chr = fgetc(fr);
}
*tmp_ptr = '\0'
tmp_chr = fgetc(fr);
tmp_ptr = tempprice;
while (tmp_chr >= '0' && tmp_chr <= '9' || tmp_chr == '.')
{
  *tmp_ptr++ = tmp_chr;
  tmp_chr = fgetc(fr);
}
float stockprice = stof(tempprice); //change string to float
```

...but that's just me.  =]  It's weird, I love regexps, but can't stand the scanf mechanisms.  Anyone else?

Comment: BTW, this is one of those situations where you make VERY sure that you know the limits of your inputs.  Whatever you use to scan the file and move it into program storage, you should be sure that extra-long strings don't end up causing buffer overflows.

Comment: thanks, this certainly works..but i think using fscanf can save code space and a little bit more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

1) I agree with user30997: I think scanf "pseudo-regex" is more trouble than it's worth.  IMHO...

2) However, I believe this is the solution you're looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[] = "GOOG|5.88";
    char price[80], ticker[80];
    int iret = sscanf (str, "%[^|]%*[|]%s", price, ticker);
    printf ("iret=%d, price=%s, ticker=%s...\n",
        iret, price,  ticker);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT: `iret=2, price=GOOG, ticker=5.88...`

Comment: Thanks paulsm4. I tried your code "%[^|]%*[|]%s", but it still doesn't work... still ticker can get the correct GOOG, but ticker cannot get the correct number

Comment: For whatever it's worth, it *is* the correct syntax, and it *does* work for me.  I'm using gcc 4.1.2 on CentOS Linux.  I didn't try any other compilers.  Q: What compiler are you using?